# How to avoid login at the same time with same credentials in a Glassfish Web App

Tags: java, authentication, glassfish

In a classic **Web Application** deployed in **Glassfish** we are looking for a way to prevent 'same' user from having multiple simultaneous logins.

Is there a way to acchieve that?

Comment: There appears a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388710/glassfish-j2ee-lightweight-way-to-configure-user-authentication-to-prevent-mult

Comment: This is not very "fresh" (11 years, 3 months ago), but thank you anyway!